# Join two tables on matching ID?

Tags: sql-server

### Question

I have a query and would like to join one column from another table based on its matching ID

### Query So far

```
SELECT DENumber, AcquiredDate, ItemDescription, ItemName, LocationID FROM dbo.Assets JOIN LocationName FROM dbo.Locations on ProductID             
WHERE DATEDIFF(YEAR, AcquiredDate, GetDate()) >= 6
```

The matching ID in both tables is `LocationID`

### Problem

My query is wrong and throws errors

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.
```

Comment: Where did you pick up the JOIN syntax? More concrete - why do you not just go and read the documentation for it? It would make clear that there is no FROM after the JOIN and that the element after the JOIN is the table name, not some field name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite your query to this:

```
SELECT DENumber, AcquiredDate, ItemDescription, ItemName, LocationName
FROM dbo.Assets INNER JOIN dbo.Locations ON Assets.LocationId = Locations.LocationId            
WHERE DATEDIFF(YEAR, AcquiredDate, GetDate()) >= 6
```

To clarify: In a JOIN, you must specify the names of both tables on either side of the `JOIN` keyword. Then, you specify the join criteria after the `ON` keyword:

```
FROM <<table1>> INNER JOIN <<table2>> ON <<join criteria>>
```

Here, we only want records that exist in both tables, which is why we use the INNER join, but you can also take all records from either the LEFT table, the RIGHT table or BOTH tables. In that case, you would do a `LEFT JOIN`, `RIGHT JOIN` our `OUTER JOIN` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT L.DENumber, A.AcquiredDate, A.ItemDescription, A.ItemName, L.LocationID
 FROM dbo.Assets A JOIN 
  ON dbo.Locations L on 
 L.ProductID  = A.ProductID        
WHERE DATEDIFF(YEAR, A.AcquiredDate, GetDate()) >= 6
```